# Why I receive error when use Cover As in Eclipse and not with Junit?

Tags: eclipse, junit, cobertura

I use Eclipse with eCobertura
I have a little project with a Controller (SpringMVC). 
I created a test (JUnit).

When I run the test from JUnit (in Eclipse IDE) all is right but when I run the command (from menu) I receive an error

My controller :

```
package ec.europa.eu.nwi.web.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * @author LEBRUJA
 */
@Controller
public class AvailibilityController {
/**
 * @param request 
 * @return mav
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/available")
public final ModelAndView available(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("available", "sample", 
            new String("availability on 0.0.1"));
    return mav;
}
}
```

My Test :

```
package ec.europa.eu.nwi.web.controller.test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.ModelAndViewAssert;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

import ec.europa.eu.nwi.web.controller.AvailibilityController;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-servlet.xml"})
public final class AvalibilityControllerTest {

private transient MockHttpServletRequest request;
private transient MockHttpServletResponse response;

@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;


private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AvalibilityControllerTest.class);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {              
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("TearDown");
}

@Test
public void testAvailable() {
    LOGGER.debug("Start testAvailable1");
    LOGGER.debug("Test only availibility of the apps");
    final AvailibilityController avc = new AvailibilityController();
    final Object mav = avc.available(request);
    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    Assert.assertTrue(mav instanceof ModelAndView);
    ModelAndViewAssert.assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType((ModelAndView)mav, "sample", String.class);
    ModelAndViewAssert.assertModelAttributeAvailable((ModelAndView)mav, "sample");
    ModelAndViewAssert.assertModelAttributeValue((ModelAndView)mav, "sample", "availability on 0.0.1");
    ModelAndViewAssert.assertViewName((ModelAndView)mav, "available");        
    final BindingResult result = mock(BindingResult.class);
    when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);        
    LOGGER.debug("End testAvailable1");
}

@Test
public void testAvailable1() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.debug("Start testAvailable");
    LOGGER.debug("Test only availibility of the apps");
    request.setMethod("GET");
    request.setRequestURI("/available.html"); 

    Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
    LOGGER.debug("Get the Model and View");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response,handler);        
    Assert.assertEquals("availability on 0.0.1", modelAndView.getModel().get("sample"));
    Assert.assertTrue(modelAndView.getModel().containsKey("sample"));
    LOGGER.debug("End testAvailable");
}
}
```

If I run with JUnit (Run As Junit), all is right but when I run Cover As .. JUnit I receive the error.

The error :

[image]

I filtered the class (from exclude configuration in Eclipse Coverage Configuration).
If I removed the filter, the junit code  is marked in red

[image]

I don't understand the error.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly is meant by "when I run the command (from menu)"? The Error you get means that the Auto-wiring of `private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping? resulted in a null reference, in other words: did not happen at all.

Comment: @Arne Sorry I run the command Cover As. Regarding your remark, why is it working with JUnit and not whith Cobertura ? I updated from private to public but I receive the same result. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in this field. Try searching for the terms "cobertura spring autowiring" on the web. There are problems in this field and some suggested solutions...

Answer (score 1):

I had

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

In my applicationContext.xml and it is running fine now

Thanks a lot